# React state doesn't work, it doesn't rerender components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have problem with react updating state. Well, I didn't touch react for a while and I want to remember some things so I've started from beginning. However, I faced a problem. The problem is that onClick event doesn't work or `useState` doesn't work. I've tried googling and couldn't find solution.

I used `useEffect` to check if there is any problem with hooks, but it displays the message from `useEffect` at the beginning so it does work. Then problem is with `onClick` or with `useState`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import style from "./App.module.css";
// import Card from "./components/ui/Card";
import Navbar from "./components/nav/Navbar";
import NavbarCart from "./components/nav/NavbarCart";
import FoodDescription from "./components/food/FoodDescription";
import FoodContainer from "./components/food/FoodContainer";
import Food from "./components/food/Food";
// import Backdrop from "./components/modal/Backdrop";
import CartModal from "./components/modal/CartModal";
// import CartContext from "./context/cart-context";

const DUMMY_FOOD = [
  { name: "Sushi", description: "Finest fish and veggeis", price: 22.99 },
  { name: "Schnitzel", description: "A german speciality!", price: 16.5 },
  {
    name: "Barbecue Burger",
    description: "American, raw, meaty",
    price: 12.99,
  },
  { name: "Green Bowl", description: "Healthy...and green...", price: 18.99 },
];

function App() {
  const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("POCCETAK");
  }, [cartOpen]);

  const onNavbarCartClcikHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setCartOpen(true);
  };
  console.log("hahah");

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar onClick={onNavbarCartClcikHandler}>
        <h1>React meals</h1>
        <NavbarCart onClick={onNavbarCartClcikHandler} />
      </Navbar>
      <FoodDescription onClick={onNavbarCartClcikHandler} />
      <FoodContainer onClick={onNavbarCartClcikHandler}>
        {DUMMY_FOOD.map((food) => (
          <Food key={food.name} value={food} />
        ))}
      </FoodContainer>
      {cartOpen ? <CartModal></CartModal> : ""}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When you click to the Navbar , in Navbar Cart Click Handler function called , setCartOpen change state , useEffect catch the change and your console.log appeared , what is a problem of rerender ? @Nijaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the issue , Put Navbar in the div or <React.Fragment> element

```
 <div onClick={onNavbarCartClcikHandler}>
          <Navbar onClick={onNavbarCartClcikHandler}>
            <h1>React meals</h1>
            <NavbarCart onClick={onNavbarCartClcikHandler} />
          </Navbar>
    </div>
```

Comment: Exactly, I forgot that onClick and overall events can be only put on HTML elements not components. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In react when you want to pass a parameter

```
onClick={(e)=> onNavbarCartClcikHandler(e)}
```

Also you are trying to trigger `onClick` event on virtual dom that's why `onClick` won't work so instead you can receive it in you child component like `FoodContainer` and triggred from real document object like `div`

Comment: that wouldn't make a difference

Comment: if you not pass event to the onNavbarCartClickHandler , it automatically will pass for you , if you want pass something else , then you are right , but this was not related with question @Salem_Raouf

Comment: Well, the problem was that I put onclick on virtual dom element as you said not on basic html element like div. Revising is mother of knowledge. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: happy its working, my pleasure